# Is it possible to run Android Test Orchestrator for specified tests only?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

Two of my Espresso tests require independent instrumentation to run properly. But the other 30+ do not. Is it possible to use Android Test Orchestrator to make 3 instrumentations (1 each for big tests, and 1 for the 30+ smaller ones)?

Comment: I would like to know this too!